# plotly bar graph - adding percentages to labels

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart using the `plotly` package in R. I want to add labels above each bar, but I've only be able to successfully add in the counts. Is it all possible to add in percentages next to each count? This is what I have:

```
fig_valve <- plot_ly(valve_df, 
                    x = ~vlvsz_c, 
                    y = ~count,
                    type = "bar",
                    hoverinfo = "x+y")
fig_valve <- fig_valve %>%
  add_text(text = ~count, 
           textposition = "top", 
           textfont = list(size = 11, color = "black"), 
           showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(title = "",
         xaxis = list(title = "Valve Size", showgrid = FALSE), 
         yaxis = list(title = "Count", showgrid = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE,
         font = t)
```

The output: [image]

I'm wondering if I can add in the percentages for each category. Greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the percentages next to the counts via `text = ~paste0(count, " (", scales::percent(count / sum(count)), ")")` where I use `scales::percent` for nice formatting. Using `mtcars` as example data, try this:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

fig_valve <- mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, name = "count") %>% 
    plot_ly( 
      x = ~cyl, 
      y = ~count,
      type = "bar",
      hoverinfo = "x+y")
fig_valve <- fig_valve %>%
  add_text(text = ~paste0(count, " (", scales::percent(count/sum(count)), ")"), 
           textposition = "top", 
           textfont = list(size = 11, color = "black"), 
           showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(title = "",
         xaxis = list(title = "Valve Size", showgrid = FALSE), 
         yaxis = list(title = "Count", showgrid = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE,
         font = t)
fig_valve
```

[image]

Comment: Stefan, this is great and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!!!